# Ubuntu session lost after inactivity

Tags: unity

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a laptop, it worked fine for the past years. Recently I tried vanilla gnome, that I uninstall it and continue to use Ubuntu desktop with a darktheme available in Tweaks. Recently my user session started to crash for no reason after some inactivity time. No restart.
I went for a walk, the PC was on, connected to power supplied, I came back the mouse was stuck after few seconds of clicking on the keyboard the ubuntu login screen was shown. All the open apps were gone, session lost, no crash report or alert.
How should I figure out the issue? Is there a specific file to look for logs?

I can provide details below. Thank you!
R

```
    System:    Host: HP Kernel: 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) dm: gdm3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP EliteBook 840 G1 v: A3009DC10303 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 198F v: KBC Version 15.59 serial: N/A
           BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: L71 Ver. 01.47 date: 04/18/2019
           Chassis: type: 10 serial: N/A
Battery    BAT0: charge: 43.9 Wh 96.3% condition: 45.6/45.6 Wh (100%) volts: 12.5/11.2
           model: Hewlett-Packard Primary serial: <filter>status: N/A
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-4300U (-MT-MCP-) arch: Haswell rev.1 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9977
           clock speeds: min/max: 800/2900 MHz 1: 1191 MHz 2: 1289 MHz 3: 1394 MHz 4: 1297 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a16
           Display Server: wayland (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915 Resolution: 1600x900@59.95hz, 2560x1440@59.91hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 20.0.8 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:9c20
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a0c
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.4.0-70-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I218-LM
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: 3080 bus-ID: 00:19.0 chip-ID: 8086:155a
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:08b1
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 756.2GB (7.2% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sdb model: TS256GMTS400 size: 256.1GB serial: <filter> temp: 26C
           ID-2: /dev/sda model: HGST_HTS725050A7 size: 500.1GB serial: <filter> temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 42G used: 27G (70%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb5
           ID-2: /home size: 49G used: 25G (53%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb6
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 296 Uptime: 6:20 Memory: 2650.3/15910.4MB Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.5.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201 running in gnome-terminal-) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: It can be a hardware problem. Can you boot from an Ubuntu Live USB and leave it overnight and see if the same thing happens with the Live USB? To so this use the **Try Ubuntu without installing** option. When the desktop opens, open a few apps like Gedit, Firefox, etc. Then leave it, go for a walk again. If it crashes the apps will be gone.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with Ubuntu 20 live USB did not show any problem... I guess something is broken in my installation. 
Maybe there is some log file to see the issues!?

Comment: Please add the new information you wrote in the comments into your original question using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1330335/edit) function. Open the app **System Log** and open it. All the different types of logs are accessible from there. I would start with reviewing the *syslog* file at the time and date you had the problem. If you find any errors in the logs, copy and paste them in your question (using the edit function).